# How to calculate hour to day in NetCDf file using scala

Tags: scala, netcdf

is there a method to convert the unit from hours to days in [this dataset](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/repository/entry/show?entryid=synth%3Ae570c8f9-ec09-4e89-93b4-babd5651e7a9%3AL2NtYXAvc3Rk) ?

```
double time(time) ;
time:units = "hours since 1800-01-01 00:00:0.0" ;
time:long_name = "Time" ;
time:delta_t = "0000-01-00 00:00:00" ;
time:avg_period = "0000-01-00 00:00:00" ;
time:standard_name = "time" ;
time:axis = "T" ;
time:actual_range = 1569072., 1895592. ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Python, it's an easy process:

The first step is to convert the numeric dates to a datetime object using [netCDF4 num2date](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.num2date).

The second step is to compute the number of days between each datetime object and the time stamp (or original date) in the `time` variable (i.e. 1800-01-01).

```
import netCDF4
import datetime

ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset('./precip.mon.mean.nc', 'r')
time = ncfile.variables['time']
# Convert from numeric times to datetime objects
dates = netCDF4.num2date(time[:], time.units)

# Compute number of days since the original date
orig_date = datetime.datetime(1800,1,1)
days_since = [(t - orig_date).days for t in dates]
```

Comment: But in our case we are using Apache Spark and scala.